# Use OpenGL ES 1.1 rendering engine with QCAR?

Tags: opengl-es, qcar-sdk

I wanna use a rendering engine with QCAR (vuforia) to build an AR app. Is it possible to incorporate a rendering engine which uses OpenGL ES 1.1 with QCAR?

I QCAR is using opengl 2.0 for sample applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QCAR supports both 1.x and 2.0 but by default 2.0 is enable. If your rendering engine only supports 1.x you can easily tweak QCAR to use 1.x by changing this:

```
USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1 := false
```

to TRUE in Android.mk file which is located under JNI folder. I assume that you are using QCAR for Android but for iOS the steps are pretty much the same.

Comment: Hi Sam. Thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestion for the rendering side? I want to use min3D with QCAR and don't know how to set min3D to use 1.1.

Comment: That's a good question. min3d does not support 2.0 so you don't need to bother anything. min3d is very slow in combination with QCAR. I encourage you to pick another rendering engine. I did it with jPCT-AE and it's really promising. Watch the result here: [QCAR + jPCT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chsHh0pEhzw)

Comment: Would you give me an overview of the entire procedure?

Comment: That's another question. Ask a new one and I will answer :)

Comment: LOL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122131/how-to-use-jpct-with-vuforia-sdk