# How to use jPCT with Vuforia SDK?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rendering, qcar-sdk

Can someone give an overview of mixing Jpct and Qualcomm Vuforia SDK? Is it a good idea to use Java rendering engine with Vuforia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the whole roll of QCAR is to compute the transformation matrix of a deformed predefined target image. It gives you two important 4x4 matrices which you can use with OpenGL to superimpose your graphics.

- **ModelView** matrix
- **Projection** matrix

if you are familiar with OpenGL, these two are enough for rendering purpose. But if you want to use a rendering engine like **jPCT**, use ModelView matrix with **camera** and extract **FOV** from Projection matrix. Take a look at the ImageTarget sample app and you will understand which part of the code you have to change.

Not to mention, you should also comment out the unnecessary rendering codes from native codes. Since jPCT is Java-based, you need to pass matrices from native codes to Java which is a JNI task. Otherwise, you may use a C++ based engine like *Ogre3D* or *OpenFramework* to be able to render in native code.

Come back and ask more if you face problem.